# Маркер • в IE 6-11

Tags: html, вёрстка, строки, internet-explorer

Простой html код
`&bull;&nbsp;Один &bull;&nbsp;Два &bull;&nbsp;Три`
в IE 6-11 выглядит как будто строке запрещён перенос.

Как это можно исправить?

- в коде: Спецсимвол "Простой маркер" • , он же `&bull;`, он же `&#8226;` и спецсимвол "Неделимый пробел" `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант решения для IE 6-9

- добавить в строке перед пробелами
  `<!--[if IE]>&shy;<![endif]-->`

- строка полностью:
  `&bull;&nbsp;Один<!--[if IE]>&shy;<![endif]--> &bull;&nbsp;Два<!--[if IE]>&shy;<![endif]--> &bull;&nbsp;Три`

Вариант решения для IE 6-11

- добавить в таблицу CSS
  `@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast:active),(-ms-high-contrast:none) {.shy:before {content:'\00AD';}} /* для IE10-11 */`
- заменить пробел на
  `<span class="shy"><!--[if IE]>&shy;<![endif]--> </span>`

- строка полностью
  `&bull;&nbsp;Один<span class="shy"><!--[if IE]>&shy;<![endif]--> </span>&bull;&nbsp;Два<span class="shy"><!--[if IE]>&shy;<![endif]--> </span>&bull;&nbsp;Три`